# Can anyone tell me the exact meaning and use of the below statement and where we must use it

Tags: c#

```
public static int Id { get; set; }
```

It does not show any error but what is the exact definition of this statement?

Comment: ...a public static property?

Comment: have you tried seeing what it does?

Comment: It's called an auto property (in this case static), and is just syntactic sugar (easy to write/read)

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is to declare a property. 
From [dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/property):

> Property. On a class, a property gets and sets values. A simplified syntax form, properties are implemented in the IL as methods.
>
> With properties, we create standard access points from external
>   places. We access Name, not GetName(). This leads to simpler code. It
>   provides data-binding features.

Answer (score -1):

This statement indicates that you declare the `getter` and `setter` of `int Id`

Where you want to `get` or `set` the value of `int id` you can call like this `id.get() & id.set()` for set some value init.

Comment: I apologize for rejecting your edit on the OP, but the ASP tag did not have anything to do with the question and the formatting of the code was perfectly fine. The only real change was some grammar with the word "showing", otherwise the question was formatted properly.

Comment: You don't call a property in C# using a get() or set() method...